# How to get only selected directory names

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have sub directories inside main directory `REPORT`. And the sub directories like `TEST`,`TEST_LNK`,`FAIL`,`FAIL_LNK`,`PASS`,`GOOD`,`GOOD_LNK`.

Now I need the sub directories which do not have `_LNK` in the name.

Example:

I need only these directories `TEST,FAIL,PASS,GOOD`.

I have a code that will give all the sub directories inside main directory.

`ls -lrt | egrep '^d' | awk '{print $9}`

Can anyone please help me to get sub directories with out `_LNK` by modifying above command?

Comment: with minimal modification to your command, add: `| grep -v "_LNK"`

Comment: when I add the above command with `ls -lrt | egrep '^d' | awk '{print $9} | grep -v "_LNK"` it is not giving any output. I want list of sub directories exist in parent directory `REPORT` wher ethe sub directories not having name ending with `_LNK`

Comment: Are you sure that there are sub-folder without "_LNK"? Can you please post the result of your original command (without grep -v)?

Comment: And now that I think about it you can also add a match into awk: `awk '!/_LNK/ {print $9}'`

Comment: I am extremely sorry...the above command `ls -lrt | egrep '^d' | awk '{print $9} | grep -v "_LNK"` is giving expected output. thank you very much

Comment: you're welcomed, however, to match directory is better to use find, see my answer below

Comment: If an answer solved your problem or helped you, please consider to accept it, see also: [how accepting works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should help you

```
ls -lrt | grep -v '_LNK'
```

Comment: I want list of sub directories exist in parent directory REPORT where the sub directories not having name ending with `_LNK`

Answer (score 3):

`ls` has `--hide` parameter for avoiding unwanted output. Use like below:

```
ls --hide='*_lnk'
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to your command, you can use `find` to recursively find all sub directories and then use `grep` to select the ones you want:

```
find . -type d -exec echo {} \; | grep -v "_LNK"
```

Here the relevant options are:

- `-type d`: select only files of type directory
- `-exec`  : execute the following command

`"{}"` is placeholder for the files that matches, while `"\;"` tells find where the command ends.

---

Another option (suggested by Toby Speight in comments) is to do all the work with find, using the `'!'` negation of the `-name` option:

```
find . -type d '!' -name '*_LNK'
```

Also, it is worth nothing that there is the `maxdepth` option that permits to set the level of recursion: `-maxdepth 1` means search only in the subdirectories (one level).